# InputListener doesn´t set a new screen

Tags: java, android, button, libgdx

I wrote the following code:

```
public void show () {
    skin = new Skin (Gdx.files.internal("PlayButton.json"));
    button = new Button(skin);
    button.setPosition(330,600);
    button.setSize(240,240);
    stage.addActor(button);
}

public void render () {
    stage.draw();
    stage.getBatch().begin();
    button.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
            }
        });
        stage.getBatch().end();
}
```

As you can see, I want the GameScreen to be shown if the button was clicked. I can click the button but there is no reaction. **How can I set a new screen correct?**

Comment: dont add listener to your button every frame. put it in your initialization part of your code which is create() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add listener to your `Button` inside your `show()` method rather than in `render()` method.

```
@Override
public void show () {
    skin = new Skin (Gdx.files.internal("PlayButton.json"));
    button = new Button(skin);
    button.setPosition(330,600);
    button.setSize(240,240);
    button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
            super.clicked(event, x, y);
        }
    });

    stage.addActor(button);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}

@Override
public void render (float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);

    stage.draw();
    stage.act();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, there is a small time of period where nothing happens when I click the button. What´s the reason for it?

Comment: may be delay due to you're using some resources in `GameScreen` class. Use `AssetManager` and load all your assets (texture, fonts, sound...) asynchronously and get your resource form assetmanager whenever you needed.